# "Unable to evaluate expression" and Async CTP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, debugging, asp.net-mvc-3, async-ctp

Some time ago I have installed the Visual Studio Async CTP

And today I have installed ASP.NET MVC 3 (not RC).

I start receiving "Unable to evaluate expression" in debug mode.

So I have uninstalled Async CTP, ASP.NET MVC 3 and all related updates but with no results.
Would be anybody so kind as to help me figure out?

Example message:

```
Unable to evaluate expression term 'struct'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full uninstall all visual studio components helped me.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is my experience. I finally got it working... and **no full uninstall of VS 2010 was required.**

First of all, I am not sure if I had installed ASP NET MVC 3 RC or not. I already had ASP NET  MVC 3 RTM and then installed Async CTP. I started getting issues described then uninstalled Async CTP and MVC 3, did not help... I later realised I had not done enough:

In control panel:

- Uninstall ASP NET MVC 3
- Uninstall ASP NET MVC 3 Visual Studio Tools
- Uninstall ASP NET Web Pages
- Uninstall ASP NET Web Pages Visual Studio Tools
- Uninstall Web Matrix

Then click on "View installed updates" in Control Panel->Uninstall A Program:

- Uninstall Async CTP
- Uninstall kb2483190

Now install ASP NET MVC 3 RTM and it should work.

Comment: +1 Thanks, it was the 2x updates in my case (seems to be the async CTP stuff as I didnt install MVC3); I do have the ASP.NET Web Pages stuff but it's not relevant

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem arises when both MVC 3 RC and .NET Framework Async CTP are installed on the same machine.

You need to uninstall MVC 3 RC but since it also comes with ASP.NET Web Pages, NuGet and a Visual Studio update those have to be removed along with it.

To proceed open a Visual Studio command prompt* with Administrator privilege and run all of the following commands:

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - Visual Studio 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 - VWD Express 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - Visual Studio 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages - VWD Express 2010 Tools" call uninstall

wmic product where name="NuGet" call uninstall

msiexec /package {BC0464FA-A0BA-3E38-85BF-DC5B3A401F48} /uninstall {3069D446-63C5-38F4-9D28-41858024419C}

msiexec /package {85076DFF-7A17-3566-9CC0-488E6E6D4494} /uninstall {3069D446-63C5-38F4-9D28-41858024419C}

If the problem still persists however uninstall .NET Framework Async CTP as well.

Answer (score 0):

This error message usually arises when there is a fairly critical error trying to load the language expression evaluator in the debugger or if the expression evaluator itself has a setup issue.  The very next thing I would try is to repair the Visual Studio installation.  That will almost certainly clear up this error.

Comment: I have read that VS repaid would not help. Anyway i dont have other options so i will try and make a report.

Comment: As I thought repair not helped me.

Comment: Full uninstall and reinstall helped me (Almost). Razor Editor is not installed so Intelisense and color highlighting not working for me.

Comment: I have fallen victim to the same issue... no solution yet.

Comment: @Aliostad, I'm meeting with the async team today and I'm going to see if they're aware of this issue and any work arounds

Comment: Thanks @Jared. In fact it is sorted now, I will post an answer now.

Comment: @JaredPar / the async team of which you speak: Hoping my fix to the question will make this a hit with the search engines. No harm to have the actual message in a blog post tho -- the error message just didnt trigger **anything**. Thanks for the efforts here!